# Android why back button is very laggy how to debug it?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have picture showing `activity` from `fragment`. When call picture and showing alright. But when i click back button it's very laggy . after some time activity is closing.

Is following image downloading library slow?(Or this `activity` alright, is resuming `fragment` slow?) I don't know how to fix this. Where is the problem? Please give me tip or solution?

```
public class Activity_detail_image extends AppCompatActivity{


    private Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail_image);

        toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        String urls = getIntent().getStringExtra("image");
//
//        SubsamplingScaleImageView iv = (SubsamplingScaleImageView)findViewById(R.id.zoom_image);
//
//        iv.setImage(ImageSource.resource(R.drawable.amestros_01));
        if(LoginActivity.isNetworkAvailable()) {
            new DownloadImageTask((SubsamplingScaleImageView) findViewById(R.id.zoom_image))
                    .execute(urls);
        } else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Check your Internet connection!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Activity_detail_image.this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            this.finish();
        }


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }
    private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        SubsamplingScaleImageView bmImage;

        public DownloadImageTask(SubsamplingScaleImageView bmImage) {
            this.bmImage = bmImage;
        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String urldisplay = urls[0];
            Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
            try {
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mIcon11;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            bmImage.setImage(ImageSource.bitmap(result));
        }
    }
```

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
    app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="right">

        <TextView
            android:gravity="center|start"
            android:id="@+id/action_title"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="4">
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <com.davemorrissey.labs.subscaleview.SubsamplingScaleImageView
            android:id="@+id/zoom_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


        </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Not sure this will fix your problem. But it's better to use image loader library like "Glide" instead, for better performance. Plus it will handle memory management as well.

Comment: Try to override onOptionsItemSelected() and see if it sill lags.  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

Answer (score 1):

Remove this

```
@Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        onBackPressed();
      }
```

and write in onCreate Method

```
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        finish();
    }
});
```

Also Use Glide or Picaso to load bitmap in imageview in onPostExecute method

Comment: Since you have the url of the image, not just in OnPostExecute, You can completely remove DownloadImageTask.
Use glide lib and use the code below to download the image to imageView. 
  Glide.with(this)
             .load(url)
             .into(imgView);

Comment: setting setNavigationOnClickListener is fast than onSupportNavigateUp. (But for my case still) For case of glide SubsamplingScaleImageView is not calculated as imageview

Comment: you can use TouchImageview for scaling image https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView

Comment: thanks even without download image when i click back button 2 seconds after activity is finishing? what should i think about this

Comment: Check log during this 2 second what's happening